# Mi login en cakePHP 3.x no funciona

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

estoy intentando hacer un loguin en cakePHP siguiendo los pasos de la documentación oficial:
https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authentication.html

pero por más que lo intente siempre que intento loguearme con cualquier user me dice que el usuario o contraseña son incorrectas, la contraseña tiene el método hash para encriptarse y aunque lo quité sigue pasando lo mismo, ya probé con iniciar sesión con un usuario sin contraseña encriptada quitando el método etc. y como estoy siguiendo la documentación no sé qué puede estar pasando.

Voy a poner los códigos de los archivos que creería tienen relevancia, en caso de que falte alguno, por favor dímelo y lo agregaré

este es el AppController

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class AppController extends Controller
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
            'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
        ]);
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');

        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'

                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()
        ]);

        $this->Auth->allow(['display', 'view', 'index', 'add']);
    }}
```

mi UsersController:

```
 <?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Rols'],
        ];
        $users = $this->paginate($this->Users);

        $this->set(compact('users'));
    }

    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Rols', 'Trainings'],
        ]);

        $this->set('user', $user);
    }

    public function add()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $rols = $this->Users->Rols->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('user', 'rols'));
    }

    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => [],
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $rols = $this->Users->Rols->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('user', 'rols'));
    }

    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $user = $this->Users->get($id);
        if ($this->Users->delete($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }

    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            $this->log($user);
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect.');
        }
    }
}
```

Mi model entity de Users:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;

/**
 * User Entity
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $password
 * @property int $rol_id
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Entity\Rol $rol
 * @property \App\Model\Entity\Training[] $trainings
 */
class User extends Entity
{
    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
     * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
     * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        'name' => true,
        'email' => true,
        'password' => true,
        'rol_id' => true,
        'rol' => true,
        'trainings' => true,
    ];

    /**
     * Fields that are excluded from JSON versions of the entity.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    protected function _setPassword($value)
    {
        if (strlen($value)) {
            $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();

            return $hasher->hash($value);
        }
    }
}
```

y por ultimo mi login.ctp:

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('email') ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('password') ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('Login') ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Comment: Ves algún error relevante en los logs de PHP?

Comment: No, no me trae errores lo unico relevante seria que en mi controlador hay un $this->log($user) despues del identify(), y reviso el log y me trae: 2022-11-02 14:34:18 Error: